# Updating a html form with multiple checkboxs using php

Tags: php, checkbox, multiple-columns, updating

I have a html form which i want to check some items in the form and then update the form.
(actually there is no order in which checkbox is going to be mark, it's totally random)
my problem is when i mark some of the checkboxes and press update my code will mark the top checkboxes in order. 
This is what i mean :

before submiting :
[image]

after submiting : [image]

this is my form code :

```
$row_counter=0;                     

if ($_SESSION['user_row_num']=="1")
{
?>
<form method="POST" action="" name="frm1">
    <table class='styled-table' cellspacing='0' border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th  scope='col' style='font-size:13px;'>number</th>
            <th  scope='col' style='font-size:13px;'>view</th>
            <th  scope='col' style='font-size:13px;'>edit</th>
            <th  scope='col' style='font-size:13px;'></th>      
        </tr>               
<?php   while($row_form = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_formsearch))
        { 
            //fetching from profile previous valuse of form access
            $query_profile_check = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE `id`='{$_SESSION['user_id']}' ");
            $row_profile = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_profile_check);

            //creating form name from forms table for profile table
            $profile_form_name="form_".$row_form['num'];
            $profile_frm_name=$row_profile[$profile_form_name];

            $a_form_aces=explode("-", $profile_frm_name);
            $frm_view=$a_form_aces[0];
            $frm_edit=$a_form_aces[1];?>    

        <tr>
            <td align='center'><input  class='styled-input' type='hidden' name='form_num[]' id='form_num' value="<?php echo $row_form['num']; ?>"/></td>
            <td align='center'><input  class='styled-input' type='text' name='form_name[]' id='form_name' value="<?php echo $row_form['name']; ?>"/></td>
            <td align='center'><input  class='styled-input' type='checkbox' name='view[]' id='view' <?php if($frm_view=="1")echo "checked"; ?> /></td>
            <td align='center'><input  class='styled-input' type='checkbox' name='edit[]' id='edit' <?php if($frm_edit=="1")echo "checked"; ?> /></td>
            <td align='center'><input  type='hidden' name='row_counter' id='row_counter' value="<?php echo $row_counter++; ?>"/></td>
        </tr>   
<?php   } ?>
    </table>

    <input  class='styled-input_2' style='padding: 5px; width: 140px;' type='submit' name='save_setting' id='save_setting' value="update" >
    <div class='cleaner h30'></div> 
    </form>
```

this is my update code :

```
<?php   
    } // end of if($_SESSION['user_row_num']=="1")                  



// Check if button name "edit-msb" is active, do this 
    if(isset($_POST['save_setting']) && $_POST['save_setting'] == 'update')
    {

            for($i=0;$i<=$_SESSION['user_count'];$i++)
            {
                $row_no = ($_REQUEST['row_counter'][$i]);
                $form_numb = $_REQUEST['form_num'][$row_no];

                if(isset($_REQUEST['view'][$row_no])){$_REQUEST['view'][$row_no]="1";}else{$_REQUEST['view'][$row_no]="0";}
                if(isset($_REQUEST['edit'][$row_no])){$_REQUEST['edit'][$row_no]="1";}else{$_REQUEST['edit'][$row_no]="0";}

                $form_access=$_REQUEST['view'][$row_no]. "-" .$_REQUEST['edit'][$row_no];
                $profile_form_num="form_". $form_numb;

                $access_query=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `profile` SET `{$profile_form_num}`='{$form_access}' WHERE `id`='{$_SESSION['user_id']}'");
            }

            if($access_query!='')
            {
                echo "<div class='cleaner h30'></div>";
                echo "<b style='color:green;margin-left:10px;font-size:15px;'>the form successfully updated.</b>";

            }




    }                   
?>
```

I want each check box shows it's updated value after i submiting the form and in the order that i marking them but i don't know where is my mistake.

Comment: did u tried to debug on all lines what `$frm_view` and `$frm_edit` holds?

Comment: I debuged the code and i'm getting :  Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 2

Comment: and this one : Notice: Undefined index: in ...        and this two error are repeating

Comment: on wich line does the error uninitialized string occur? the two errors repeating means that your two vars holds nothing. BTW why r u using _REQUEST? use _POST instead cause _REQUEST can hold _GET also and can cause some trouble if two vars are given with same name

Comment: it shows this error for this two lines : $row_no = ($_REQUEST['row_counter'][$i]);
                $form_numb = $_REQUEST['form_num'][$row_no];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed your code from checkbox into select option and it's working see if it'll work for you

form code :

```
<form method="POST" action="" name="frm1">
 <table class='styled-table' cellspacing='0' border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th  scope='col' style='font-size:13px;'>form number</th>
    <th  scope='col' style='font-size:13px;'>form name</th>
    <th  scope='col' style='font-size:13px;'>view</th>
    <th  scope='col' style='font-size:13px;'>edit</th>
    <th  scope='col' style='font-size:13px;'></th>      
    </tr>               
<?php   while($row_form = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_formsearch))
        { 
            //fetching from profile previous valuse of form access
            $query_profile_check = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE `id`='{$_SESSION['user_id']}' ");
            $row_profile = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_profile_check);

            //creating form name from forms table for profile table
            $profile_form_name="form_".$row_form['num'];
            $profile_frm_name=$row_profile[$profile_form_name];

            $a_form_aces=explode("-", $profile_frm_name);
            $frm_view=$a_form_aces[0];
            $frm_edit=$a_form_aces[1];?>    

    <tr>
        <td align='center'><input  class='styled-input'  type='text' name='form_num[]' id='form_num' value="<?php echo $row_form['num']; ?>"/></td>
        <td align='center'><input  class='styled-input'  type='text' name='form_name[]' id='form_name' value="<?php echo $row_form['name']; ?>"/></td>
        <td align='center'>
            <select class='styled-input'  name='view[]' id='view'  />
                <option value="<?php echo $frm_view; ?>"><?php if($frm_view=="1"){echo "yes";}else{echo "no";} ?></option>
                <option></option>
                <option value="1" style="color:#1A75FF;">yes</option>
                <option value="0" style="color:red;">no</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td align='center'>
            <select class='styled-input' name='edit[]' id='edit' />
                <option value="<?php echo $frm_edit; ?>" ><?php if($frm_edit=="1"){echo "yes";}else{echo "no";} ?></option>
                <option></option>
                <option value="1" style="color:#1A75FF;">yes</option>
                <option value="0" style="color:red;">no</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td align='center'><input  type='hidden' name='row_counter' id='row_counter' value="<?php echo $row_counter++; ?>"/></td>
     </tr>   
<?php   } ?>
</table>
```

update code :

```
<?php   

// Check if button name "edit-msb" is active, do this 
    if(isset($_POST['save_setting']) && $_POST['save_setting'] == 'update')
    {


            for($i=0;$i<$_SESSION['user_count'];$i++)
            {
                //$row_no = ($_REQUEST['row_counter'][$i]);


                $form_access=$_POST['view'][$i]. "-" .$_POST['edit'][$i];
                echo $profile_form_num="form_". $_POST['form_num'][$i];echo"<br>";
                echo $form_access;echo"<br>";

                $access_query=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `profile` SET `{$profile_form_num}`='{$form_access}' WHERE `id`='{$_SESSION['user_id']}'");


            }

            if($access_query!='')
            {
                echo "<div class='cleaner h30'></div>";
                echo "<b style='color:green;margin-left:10px;font-size:15px;'>form successfully updated.</b>";
            }

    }                   
?>
```

Comment: actually it worked like charm. but wish it could be done with checkboxes

Comment: it could be done using checkboxes, all u have to do is pass them an value attr and handle this instead of the yes|no from this example with select options